# gapi is not defined when loading React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign In ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)) using React.
I found a question that has solved this in past [Using google sign in button with react 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640234/using-google-sign-in-button-with-react-2)

I replicated the same steps as mentioned. In my `index.html` I do

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleLoaded" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function triggerGoogleLoaded() {
            console.log("google event loaded");
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('google-loaded'));
        }
    </script>
```

Then my `Component` looks like

```
var LoginButton = React.createClass({

    onSignIn: function(googleUser) {
        console.log("user signed in"); // plus any other logic here
    },

    renderGoogleLoginButton: function() {
        console.log('rendering google signin button');
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 200,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'light',
            'onsuccess': this.onSignIn
        })
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        window.addEventListener('google-loaded',this.renderGoogleLoginButton);
    },

    render: function() {
        let displayText = "Sign in with Google";
        return (
            <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
        );
    }

});

export default LoginButton;
```

When I run the program using `yarn start`, I get

```
/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/webs/google-login/src/LoginButton.js
  11:9   error    'gapi' is not defined                             no-undef
  26:13  warning  'displayText' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)
```

The complete source code is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/google-login-with-react

Could someone please help me understand my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks to me like you're loading the google apis as a script tag, which we'd expect to set `window.gapi` to the google api. However, you're then running eslint or some other checker, and that has no idea that `window.gapi` is supposed to exist. It's failing because it sees you using an undeclared variable.

A cheap fix is to tell Eslint that you know what you are doing;

```
/* global gapi */
```

Put this at the top of your file and eslint will treat `gapi` as a known global variable.

Comment: Thanks @steve, this has helped me to get get the button, now I am stuck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767485/react-unable-to-perform-google-sign-in-no-errors-are-visible, do you know where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Put it in componentDidMount or constructor:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        this.auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '436676563344-.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        });

        this.auth2.attachClickHandler(this.refs.googleButton, {},
            (googleUser) => {
                this.googleLogin(googleUser.getBasicProfile());
            }, (error) => {

            });
    });
}
```

Comment: I still get the OP's error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined`) with this. Are you defining gapi somewhere?

Comment: does you put <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleLoaded" async defer></script> before your script ?

Comment: Do you know how I can get the gapi to work with `react-native`?

Comment: @Bomber sorry, but i don't know :(

Answer (score 5):

You can also try the package [gapi-script](https://github.com/partnerhero/gapi-script), this package provides the gapi instantly, so you don't have to wait any script to load, just import it and use:

```
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
```

Comment: Not a good solution since gapi script is updated by Google dynamically and this is just a hard copy of the script. You can end up with an outdated version of the script and your application may stop working.

Comment: Yes that's true and I agree with you, I don't recommend this package for companies and enterprise projects, only to small projects to study and etc.

Comment: The package was updated, now there is a function to download and use the real script from google's link.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you’re not using async defer, which will cause race conditions between window.gapi.someMethod() and your script loading

In short, remove **async defer** from your script tag in your index.html.

**before**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleLoaded" async defer></script>
```

**after**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleLoaded"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simillar issue.

I use 'react-snap' for SEO. It blocked me to use 'gapi'. I found navigator.userAgent 'ReactSnap'.

```
if (navigator.userAgent !== 'ReactSnap') {
    // some code to dynamically load a script
    let myScript = document.createElement('script')
    myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js')
    document.body.appendChild(myScript)
}
```

I solved a problem.
It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

This workout helped me(place this code in index.html above main scripts):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let tokenClient; // here you can pass client token after authentication
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      /**
       * Callback after api.js is loaded.
       */
      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient);
      }

      /**
       * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
       * discovery doc to initialize the API.
       */
      async function initializeGapiClient() {
        gapiInited = true;
      }

      /**
       * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
       */
      function gisLoaded() {
        gisInited = true;
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
```