# React Unable to perform Google Sign In, no errors are visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

My original challange started with [gapi is not defined when loading React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751318/gapi-is-not-defined-when-loading-react-component).

This has helped me reach to part where I see Google Sign In screen 
[image]

and also interact with it as
[image]

However, when I click on the account, the Google Page goes away and nothing happens, no consent screens, no error . I am using Yarn and my application runs on port `3000`.

My React Component looks like

```
/* global gapi */
import React from 'react';


class LoginButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this);
    }


    onSignIn(googleUser) {
        console.log("user signed in"); // plus any other logic here
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '793065532423867-j06sr2rufh7ns1kepcdolt9l22ph5pso.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess={this.onSignIn}></div>
        );
    }

}

export default LoginButton;
```

Also, my google client setting look like
[image]
[image]
[image]

As I am working locally, I believe I do not have to do Domain Verification at this time

Could some one please help me understand the issue and how to debug/fix it?
The complete repository is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/google-login-with-react

Thanks in advance